# Compare directories on file names

Tags: python, directory, compare, filenames

I need to compare the file names of two directories A and B.

A contains more files than B (around 15000/20000 respectively) with same name/different content.

I have:

**dirA:** `'doctor_Weiss.csv', 'doctor_Urlici.csv', 'doctor_Basler J. Rudolph.csv'`

**dirB:** `'doctor_Weiss.csv', 'doctor_Urlici.csv'`

I need all the files in dirA-dirB (from dirA):

**diffAB:** `'doctor_Basler J. Rudolph.csv'`

I tried:

```
import os
from os.path import join

fpA = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\A\docs'):
    for name in files:
        fpA[name] = 1
fpB = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\B\docs'):
    for name in files:
        fpB[name] = 1

 a = []
 for name in fpA.keys():
     if not(name in fpB.keys()):
         a.append(name)
```

Didn't work. 'a' contains all the files from B and not just A-B.

I also tried to traverse both directories and create sets of files but did not work either (again all the files from B).

Thanks for your help

Comment: In the last for loop, you wrote `fpa.keys()` instead of `fpA.keys()` and `fpb.keys()` instead of `fpB.keys()`. Is that just a typo?

Comment: I don't think you should edit the question here.. The user referring it later will get confused.

Comment: sorry, I thought it was helpful

Comment: Sure.. not a problem

Comment: Do these directories have subdirectories or are they flat?

Comment: What does "around 15000/20000 respectively" mean, exactly? Because it sounds like A contains 15000 and B contains 20000, but you said A contains more.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I meant 20000/15000 respectively

Answer (score 4):

You can use set to get difference of files in this way.

```
import os
from os.path import isfile
list_A = [x for x in os.listdir(dirA) if isfile(x)]
list_B = [x for x in os.listdir(dirB) if isfile(x)]
diff = set(list_A) - set(list_B)
```

Comment: It worked with a slight difference: list_A = [x for x in os.listdir(dirA)] and list_B = [x for x in os.listdir(dirB)]. For some reason if I added isfile(x) len(list_A)=0 and len(list_B)=0. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

In the last for loop, you wrote `fpa.keys()` instead of `fpA.keys()` and `fpb.keys()` instead of `fpB.keys()`. Use the appropriate variable names, and it will work. It is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
>>> from os import listdir
>>> set(listdir(dirA)).difference(listdir(dirB))
```

`os.listdir` get all the files under current directory, then use `set.difference()` to get the difference in dirA but not in dirB.

Comment: thanks, still for some reason the difference is just the empty set

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes in path names! And - as suggested - rename `fpa` to `fpA` and `fpb` to `fpB`. Then your example will work.

```
import os
from os.path import join

fpA = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\A\\docs'): # <- escape backslash
    for name in files:
        fpA[name] = 1
fpB = {}
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\B\\docs'): # <- escape backslash
    for name in files:
        fpB[name] = 1

a = []
for name in fpA.keys():
    if not(name in fpB.keys()):
        a.append(name)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried all your suggestions but keep on getting all the files (B) and not just A-B. Any other advice?